# how i will get data from owner

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I have 4 classes `Township`, `Society`, `Flat` and `Owner`. If I enter the owner name, how will I get all data from `Owner` class?

```
public class TestSociety {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, TownShip> township = initializeTownShip();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter name of owner");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();

    }

    private static HashMap<Integer, TownShip> initializeTownShip() {
        // putting township into the hashmap
        HashMap<Integer, TownShip> township = new HashMap<Integer, TownShip>();
        for (int tid = 1; tid < 5; tid++) {
            township.put(tid, new TownShip("topaz", getListOfSociety(tid)));
        }
        return township;
    }

    private static List<Society> getListOfSociety(int tid) {
        // putting societies into the list
        List<Society> listOfSociety = new ArrayList<Society>();
        for (int societyId = 1; societyId < 5; societyId++) {
            listOfSociety.add(new Society(societyId,
                    "society name" + societyId, getListofFlat(societyId)));
        }
        return listOfSociety;
    }

    private static List<Flat> getListofFlat(int societyId) {
        // putting flats into the list
        List<Flat> listOfFlat = new ArrayList<Flat>();
        for (int flatId = 1; flatId <= 10; flatId++) {
            listOfFlat.add(new Flat(flatId, flatId + 1, new Owner("firstname"
                    + flatId, "lastname" + flatId, flatId * 1234)));
        }
        return listOfFlat;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code (your classes).

Comment: You should post your `Township` and `Flat` classes as well.

Comment: Post `Owner`, too.  What data does `Owner` contain that you are trying to get at?  How are `Owner`s populated/initialized?  For starters, you'll probably want to implement a method to retrieve an instance of `Owner` to "get all the data" from (note: depending on your use case, you may want a secondary facility to pick an `Owner` if duplicate names are possible).

Comment: thank you guys ,and sorry for the incomplete code

Answer (score 0):

I just tried this one and it will work,its bad coding actually but i want do this as dummy code,i just created one method and iterate all list by using 3 for each loop

```
private static void printOwnerAddressOnContainsStr(List<TownShip> townships, String fname) {
        for (TownShip town : townships) {
            /* System.out.println(town); */
            List<Society> societies = town.getListOfSociety();
            for (Society society : societies) {

                List<Flat> flats = society.getListOfFlat();
                // System.out.println(flats);
                for (Flat flat : flats) {
                    Owner owner = flat.getOwner();
                    // System.out.println(owner);
                    if (owner.getFirstName().contains(fname)){
                        System.out.println("Address is");
                        System.out.println("Owners name :"+owner.getFirstName()+" "+owner.getLastName());
                        System.out.println("flat no: "+flat.getfNo()+" "+society.getsName()+" "+town.gettName());
                        System.out.println("");

                        /*System.out.println(town.gettName()+" "+society.getsName()+" "+flat.getfNo()+" "+owner);
                        //System.out.println(fname);
                        //System.exit(1);
*/                  }
                }

            }

        }
    }
```